# Trying to iterate through an array to send signed transactions results in one failure and one success

Tags: web3js, ganache, ethereumjs-tx

I'm trying to iterate through an array of address/key pairs and send a transaction from each one. When I do this on `testrpc` with an array of the account info for two different accounts, one transaction succeeds (ie I get the transaction information, both in the console log and in my `ganache-cli`) and the other fails (returns an empty error, no transaction hash).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("ws://localhost:8545/"));
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
var numWallets = 0;

wallets.forEach(function(account) {
  var addr = account.address;
  var key;
  web3.eth.getBalance(addr).then( (result) => {

    web3.eth.getGasPrice()
    .then((gasPrice) => {
      var gasLimit = 25000;
      web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addr).then( (nonce) => {
        var nonce = nonce.toString();
        addr = account.address;
        key = account.key;
        key = key.slice(2);

        var rawTransaction = {
          "from": addr,
          "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
          "gasPrice": web3.utils.toHex(gasPrice),
          "gasLimit": web3.utils.toHex(gasLimit),
          "to": destinationAddr,
          "value": result - (gasPrice * gasLimit),

        };

        var privKey = Buffer.from(key, 'hex');

        var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction); // This object has the same output in both iterations

        tx.sign(privKey);
        var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

        var transaction = web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
        transaction.on('receipt', receipt => {
            console.log(receipt);
            numWallets++;
            if (numWallets == wallets.length) {
                // further logic
                console.log("finished iteration");
            }
        });
        transaction.on('error', console.log);
});
```

Comment: Is this even valid JavaScript syntax? `var numWallets++;` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I re-typed out my code and that was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried logging `key` from right before you use it? My guess it that this is just a variable capture issue and you're not really using both keys.

Comment: Just checked, the key is correct :(

Comment: To be extra clear, you're seeing two different values logged for `key`? And you're logging from within the `getTransactionCount` callback?

Comment: How is that possible? Where are `addr` and `key` declared? I'm not sure what JavaScript's behavior is if you assign to a variable that hasn't been declared yet. (If it's declared somewhere in the outer scope, you should see the issue I described.)

Comment: As an example of the issue I'm concerned about, try this: `[1,2,3].forEach(account => { foo = account * 2; setTimeout(() => { console.log(foo); }, 2000); });`. You should get `6` each time, because each iteration of the loop is overwriting the `foo` variable. (It seems that the implicit declaration makes it global in scope.)

Comment: Interesting. I did redefine `key` and `addr` right before I create the transaction when I was checking that, which is why I probably didn't have that issue, but when I log the `Tx` object that I create, I get the same "raw" value at both iterations. Perhaps that's why it's failing?

Comment: I no longer understand what your code looks like. Could you share the latest version (with the log statements)?

Comment: Just updated my code, let me know if that makes sense. Thanks so much for the help :)

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do this back and forth. The code you've shared won't run (missing a definition of `wallets`) and doesn't have any log statements whatsoever. I've given you my best guess as to the issue.